# Coverting MySQL SQL statements to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql

I am installing a product which needs a database - it can use any database as long as there is a jdbc connector available for it. However, the installation guide has instructions only on how to make it work with MySQL.

I am running it with SQL Server Express.

These are the instructions for MySQL

```
CREATE DATABASE proddb;
CREATE USER 'proddbusr'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';
CREATE USER 'proddbusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';
USE proddb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'proddbusr'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'proddbusr'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The CREATE DATABASE statement works fine on SQL Server.

However, the next statement chokes. It seems like the db name shouldn't be in quotes in SQL Server. However, I am not sure what is the equivalent for '%' in SQL Server. Likewise for `'proddb'@'localhost'`.

SQL Server also chokes on `*.*` in the GRANT statement.

Can someone who is familiar with SQL Server, help me convert all these statements to the equivalent statements for SQL Server?

**UPDATE:**

Gone through the links provided by bartlaarhoven.

```
CREATE DATABASE proddb;
CREATE LOGIN proddbusr with PASSWORD = 'thepassword';
CREATE USER proddbusr for LOGIN proddb;
```

Upto this works.

However, it's not clear how username@'%' and username@'localhost translates in SQL Server.

Also after that.

```
USE proddb;
```

This works.

The next statement has problems.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to proddb;
```

SQL Server doesn't recognize *.*.

I changed this to

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to proddb;
```

This gives me the error `The ALL permission is deprecated and maintained only for compatibility. It DOES NOT imply ALL permissions defined on the entity.`.

Anyway, in SQL Server Management Express, I did the following. Right Click on user proddb inside database proddb -> Properties. Give all possible permissions in both the 'Owned Schemas' and 'Database Role Memberships' windows except for the 2 deny permissions in each. Is this something similar to `Grant all privileges'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server works differently with this. You create a [LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) with a password for a user, which is independent of its hostname or something like that.

Then you grant access to the database by creating a [USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) on the database for a certain LOGIN.

Then you [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx) rights to the USER.

Read these links and you'll get what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out. What about the @'%' and @'localhost'? Is there any equivalent for that in SQL Server? Also for the `*.*`?

Comment: Its also not clear what's the difference between 'Create user abcd from login abcd` and  'Create user abcd for login abcd`?

Comment: The "for" and "from" are the same, just different syntax to comply to different (legacy) SQL languages. As I said, the @'%' or @'localhost' don't exist in SQL server; if you have a valid login and you can make a network connection to the server, you can login.

Comment: For the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*`, you can better add this user (so the user on database-level, not the login) to the role sysadmin. This is a predefined role where you can do everything you'll need, so just adding this user to this role will give you the necessary permissions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx (for SQL 2012; older versions use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750(v=sql.105).aspx. Or just the right-click menu on the database user in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a 'sysadmin' role at the database level. I right clicked on the user & gave it all other roles in both the 'Owned Schemas' and 'Database Role Memberships' windows except for the 2 deny roles in each.

Comment: Ah, sorry, `sysadmin` is the server-wide administrator role. My mistake. I meant `db_owner`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx That implies all the other roles, so simply checking `db_owner` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server you create an Login/User look this:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE LOGIN USER01
WITH PASSWORD =  'PASSword'
```

Then you use GRANT like this to grant alter to any database:

```
USE master
GO 
GRANT ALTER to any DATABASE TO USER01
GO
```